# Summarise row data by removing blanks and use heading (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking for some help with summarising subject data.

We have 550 pupils who select subjects and our system outputs the information into a Google Sheet like this https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13rKygFBINl6nBBlHch0Gqo39iaoEYPTBfVCxoAs3QP4/edit?usp=sharing

I want the info to come out summarised, so we see the user info and the subjects they chose.

So this would mean when a cell is found to contain text along the row to reference the column heading and put this information into the second sheet under the subject 1 heading.

I have tried to show in sheet 2 called "Should look like this" so you can get an idea of what it should look like.

Is this possible in Google Sheets?

Comment: Yes, it certainly is possible, and there are many ways to do this. You can look into the query formula https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here is a copy of your sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GSdxBfceQc8DGNn89KzvHyV8cGQEUi4e4yhbH7RAp-o/edit?usp=sharing) with the solution in cell A2 on the tab called Classes By Student.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({Data!A2:E&CHAR(10),IF(Data!F2:AX="",,Data!F1:AX1&CHAR(10))}),,9^9))),CHAR(10)&" ",0,0)))
```

It is also possible to make a similar transformation that i've done on another tab called Students by Class.

QUERY() smush can be a powerful tool for problems like this.  it consists of leveraging the query "header" argument to smush together entire columns of data all together, before splitting them back out without missing spaces.

Comment: Thank you so much for this it's very much appreciated :)

Comment: you have been a huge help. I have a new problem I have just posted if you are able to take a look at it. You seem to be the Google Sheets expert.